# Light websites and blog, MVC3 or WebMatrix?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webmatrix

I need help with my decision. I want to make my own website and blog. I don´t want to use any blog engine and I want to learn as much as possible (not just create website). And I don´t know if I should use MVC3 or WebMatrix. What is better for blog and websites? I think WebMatrix but when I use MVC3 I think I could learn more (not just as normal user but as programmer). What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“I want to learn as much as possible” = definitely choose MVC. WebMatrix's goal is to hide as much as possible.

Comment: Actually, WebMatrix's goal is to provide a simple on-ramp to the more powerful (and thus more complicated) Microsoft Web Platforms. The main reason Razor is supported in both WebMatrix and MVC is so that WebMatrix apps can be upgraded to MVC.

Comment: Agree with anurse. Have you looked at WebMatrix? It isn't Web Forms. Completely the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to read Rob Conery's blog post about web matrix:

http://blog.wekeroad.com/microsoft/someone-hit-their-head

It's quite revealing about how powerful webmatrix is.

That said I use MVC3 because I am a C# programmer at heart.

Comment: I think he already read that.  Go down to the comments and Liborek asks almost exactly the same question.

Comment: Yes, I read that. I was just not sure what to use and what to learn.

Comment: In Webmatrix you can also use C#.  It has the full .net framework behind it just like Webforms and MVC.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how much you know now, and how quickly you want to get the site done. If you know the ASP.NET framework or are familiar the the MVC model, you should be OK with ASP.NET MVC. If you are new to web development, or ASP.NET, WebMatrix may be a better starting point for you.

Answer (score 1):

MVC3 can be used with the Razor view engine.  WebMatrix allows you to integrate MVC as well.

If you want to learn the most, learn them all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are an absolute beginner then [WebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/WebMatrix) will get you started quickly and give context to some of the issues and solutions you will come across programming using Asp.net MVC